# Applying a regular expression to a text file Python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
#returns same result i.e. only the first line as many times as 'draws'
infile = open("results_from_url.txt",'r')

file =infile.read()                                       # essential to get correct formatting
for line in islice(file, 0, draws):                       # allows you to limit number of draws
    for line in re.split(r"Wins",file)[1].split('\n'):
        mains.append(line[23:38])                         # slices first five numbers from line
        stars.append(line[39:44])                         # slices last two numbers from line

infile.close()
```

I am trying to use the above code to iterate through a list of numbers to extract the bits of interest. In this attempt to learn how to use regular expressions in Python 3, I am using lottery results opened from the internet. All this does is to read one line and return it as many times as I instruct in the value of 'draws'. Could someone tell me what I have done incorrectly, please. Does re 'terminate' somehow? The strange thing is if I copy the file into a string and run this routine, it works. I am at a loss - problem 'reading' a file or in my use of the regular expression?

Comment: We can't help without knowing the format of the file, without knowing what the "bits of interest" are, and without knowing what the (incorrect) output is. Could _you_ debug a program if all you know is "it doesn't work"? Please provide some examples of input and expected output; and if you want to know why your code doesn't work, give us the incorrect output (or exception traceback) as well.

Comment: I am sorry! The file is from the url:http://lottery.merseyworld.com/cgi-bin/lottery?days=19&Machine=Z&Ballset=0&order=1&show=1&year=0&display=CSV. Basically I want to extract the numbers of each draw ( This is not an exercise in solving the lottery, merely to try to gain the skill necessary to parse any file). At the moment all the function returns is the first 'set' of numbers correctly as the first five numbers into mains and the last two into stars and does not iterate through all of the lines of the file.  I am not sure how to place code into a comment field unfortunately

Comment: >>> re_numbers()
Enter number of draws to examine 2
Main numbers were:  [' 01,03,31,42,46', ' 01,03,31,42,46'] Stars were:  ['04,11', '04,11'] is an example of the output i.e. the top line has been parsed and returned twice instead of going through, in this case, two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you why your code doesn't work, because I cannot reproduce the result you're getting. I'm also not sure what the purpose of

```
for line in islice(file, 0, draws):
```

is, because you never use the `line` variable after that, you immediately overwrite it with

```
for line in re.split(r"Wins",file)[1].split('\n'):
```

Plus, you could have used `file.split('Wins')` instead of `re.split(r"Wins",file)`, so you aren't really using regex at all.

---

Regex is a tool to find data of a certain format. Why do you use it to split the input text, when you could use it to find the data you're looking for?

What is it you're looking for? A sequence of seven numbers, separated by commas. Translated into regex:

```
(?:\d+,){7}
```

However, we want to group the first 5 numbers - the "mains" - and the last 2 numbers - the "stars". So we'll add two named capture groups, named "mains" and "stars":

```
(?P<mains>(?:\d+,){5})(?P<stars>(?:\d+,){2})
```

This pattern will find all numbers you're looking for.

---

```
import re

data= open("infile.txt",'r').read()

mains= []
stars= []

pattern= r'(?P<mains>(?:\d+,){5})(?P<stars>(?:\d+,){2})'
iterator= re.finditer(pattern, data)
for count in range(int(input('Enter number of draws to examine: '))):
    try:
        match= next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        print('no more matches')
        break

    mains.append(match.group('mains'))
    stars.append(match.group('stars'))

print(mains,stars)
```

This will print something like `['01,03,31,42,46,'] ['04,11,']`. You may want to remove the commas and convert the numbers to ints, but in essence, this is how you would use regex.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go through your solution which I am sure will teach me how to use reggae better.

Comment: Can one prevent the last comma in each set from being returned i.e. get ['01,03,31,42,46']['04,,11']?

Comment: @user1478335: Of course. Use `(?P<mains>(?:\d+,){4}\d+),(?P<stars>\d+,\d+)`.